Definite Integral $\int_{0}^{1} \log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \, d u$
My Attempt
Consider the integral
\begin{align*}
    I_1 &= \int_{0}^{1} \log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \, d u.
\end{align*}
Integrating by parts, letting $a=\log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$ and $\, d b = \, d u$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
    d a = -\frac{1}{3u^{2/3}(1-u^{1/3})} \, d u \quad \text{and} \quad b = u,
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align}
    \nonumber I_1 &= \left[ u\log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \right]_{0}^{1} - \frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{u^{1/3}}{1-u^{1/3}} \, d u\\
    &= \left[ u\log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \right]_{0}^{1} - \frac{1}{3} I_2. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align*}
    I_2 &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{u^{1/3}}{1-u^{1/3}} \, d u.
\end{align*}
Letting $v=1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}$, we have
\begin{align*}
    u=(1-v)^{3} \quad \text{and} \quad \, d u = -3(1-v)^2 \, d v.
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
    I_2 &= \int_{1}^{0} \frac{1-v}{v} \left[ -3(1-v)^2 \right] \, d v\\
    &= 3 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-v)^3}{v} \, d v\\
    &= 3 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-3v+3v^2-v^3}{v} \, d v\\
    &= 3 \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{1}{v} - 3 + 3v - v^2 \right) \, d v\\
    &= 3 \left[ \log(v) - 3v + \frac{3}{2}v^2 - \frac{1}{3}v^3 \right]_{0}^{1}.
\end{align*}
Substituting into equation (1), we have
\begin{align*}
    I_1 &= \left[ u\log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \right]_{0}^{1} - \frac{1}{3} \left\{ 3 \left[ \log(v) - 3v + \frac{3}{2}v^2 - \frac{1}{3}v^3 \right]_{0}^{1} \right\}\\
    &= \left[ u\log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \right]_{0}^{1} - \left[ \log(v) - 3v + \frac{3}{2}v^2 - \frac{1}{3}v^3 \right]_{0}^{1}\\
    &= \left[ \lim_{u\to 1} u\log(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}) - 0 \right] + \left[ -\frac{11}{6} - \left( \lim_{v\to 0} \log(v) + 0 \right) \right]\\
    &= -\frac{11}{6} + \left[ \lim_{u\to 1} u\log(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}) - \lim_{v\to 0} \log(v) \right]\\
    &= -\frac{11}{6} + \lim_{u\to 1} \left[ u\log(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}) - \log(1-u) \right]\\
    &= -\frac{11}{6} + 0\\
    &= -\frac{11}{6}.
\end{align*}
Question
I am not sure whether I am integrating correctly or not. I can't seem to prove (or further elaborate) the last limit, which is
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{u\to 1} \left[ u\log(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}) - \log(1-u) \right],
\end{align*}
to be zero. Can anyone help me with this problem? Any help/feedback is much appreciated. Thank you!

Are you interested in alternative methods?

@DavidGalea I am! Please feel free to send in any ideas you have in mind. However, if possible, I would prefer the alternative to still be in the realm of the undergraduate calculus world. Thanks!

When you integrate by parts, the two terms separately diverge as $u \nearrow 1$, owing to the $\log$ terms, but the diverging parts turn out to cancel.
We can avoid the issues of divergence when integrating by parts by choosing an antiderivative of $3 (v - 1)^2$ for which the two terms cancel separately. We can see that it's the constant term of the antiderivative that gives rise to the diverging parts, so we choose the antiderivative with zero constant term, namely, $v^3 - 3 v^2 + 3 v$. Then,
\begin{multline}
\int_0^1 3 (v - 1)^2 \log v \,dv
= \left.\left(v^3 - 3 v^2 + 3 v\right) \log v\right\vert_0^1 - \int_0^1 \left(v^3 - 3 v^2 + 3 v\right) \cdot \frac1v \,dv \\
= -{\int_0^1} \left(v^2 - 3 v + 3\right) dv
= -\frac{11}6 .
\end{multline}

Such a concise answer! I love it. Thank you very much, Travis! However, can you please elaborate more on how the constant term of the antiderivative is the term that gives rise to the diverging parts? I haven't understood that statement much, and I am indulged in understanding this simple problem even more. Really appreciate the help!

You're welcome. We can write a general antiderivative of $(v - 1)^2$ as $v^3 - 3 v^2 + 3 v + C$. The first term in the expression produced by applying integration by parts to $\int_\epsilon^1 3 (v - 1)^2 \log v$ is $$\left.(v^3 - 3 v^2 + 3 v + C) \log v\right\vert_\epsilon^1 = \epsilon^3 \log \epsilon - 3 \epsilon^2 \log \epsilon + 3 \epsilon \log \epsilon + C \log \epsilon .$$ But this expression diverges as $\epsilon \searrow 0$ unless $C = 0$.

Ah, I see... that clears things for me. Thank you so much!

You're welcome!

You can use series to evaluate the integral. In fact,
$$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{1} \log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \, d u\\
&=&-\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{u^{\frac n3}}{n}\;du=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{u^{\frac n3}}{n}\;du\\
&=&-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3}{n(n+3)}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+3}\bigg)\\
&=&-\bigg(1-\frac14+\frac12-\frac15+\frac13-\frac16+\frac14-\frac17+\frac15-\frac18+\frac16-\frac19+\cdots)\\
&=&-(1+\frac12+\frac13)\\
&=&-\frac{11}{6}.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Wonderful and fast(+1)!

What a great way to solve this integral. Thank you for the insight!

@KarelDwinugrohoBowosebua, thanks.

This elegant solution also suggests an integral representation for the $n$th harmonic number, $H_n = -\int_0^1 \log \left(1 - u^{\frac1n}\right) ,du = -n \int_0^1 v^{n - 1} \log(1 - v) ,dv$.

At first, your notation is not mathematically correct, because $\left[ u\log\left(1-u^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \right]_{0}^{1}$ diverges and it leads into an undefined expression of type $\infty-\infty$. The correct way of doing that would be either introducing the limit at this point or calculating the primitive function first and then assigning the values.
You should also use $\lim_{u\to1^-}$ instead of $\lim_{u\to1}$ as the function $\log(1-u)$ is undefined past $u=1$.
You evaluated the limit wrongly. This is, what you should get:$$
\lim_{u\to1^-}\left(u\log\left(1-u^\frac13\right)-\log(1-u)\right)=\lim_{u\to1^-}\left(\log\left(1-u^\frac13\right)-\log(1-u)\right)=\\=\log\lim_{u\to1^-}\frac{1-u^\frac13}{1-u}\stackrel{l'H}{=}\log\lim_{u\to1^-}\frac{-\frac{1}{3u^\frac23}}{-1}=-\log3
$$

Wow, thank you for your response! I find it very helpful that you pointed out how I write my notation, as I am currently writing my undergraduate thesis. Also, thank you for identifying my mistake in evaluating the limit, and I am currently discussing this with @Y.D.X. to further understand where I did wrongly. Cheers!

We first find its primitive by letting  $u=(1-x)^3$, then via integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \ln \left(1-u^{1/3}\right) d u 
& =\int \ln x d(1-x)^3 \\
& =(1-x)^3 \ln x-\int \ln x d (1-x)^3 \\
& =(1-x)^3 \ln x-\int\left(\frac{1}{x}-3+3 x-x^2\right) d x \\
& =(1-x)^3 \ln x-\ln x+3 x-\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}\\&=(-3x+3x^2-x^3)\ln x+3 x-\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $$\int_0^1 \ln \left(1-u^{1/3}\right) d u =\left[(-3x+3x^2-x^3)\ln x+3 x-\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_1^0=-\frac{11}{6} 
$$
Footnote:
For any natural number $k$, $$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} x^k \ln x & =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln x}{x^{-k}} \quad  \left(\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right) \\
& =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-k x^{-k-1}} \\
& =-\frac{1}{k} \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} x^k \\
& =0
\end{aligned}
$$

I've never actually understood how to manipulate the variable of integration to be anything other than just one variable, i.e. $dx$, $dy$, etc. For your answer in particular, I can't quite understand how you move from the first line to the second, and then from the second to the third. Do you have any reference to this kind of notation? Or perhaps do you mind explaining it for me? Much thanks!

@Hume2's deduction is right, but @Karel gives a wrong question: In the last 3 “$=$” in $I_1 = \cdots$, $v$ should be $1 - u^{1/3}$ rather than $1-u$.

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$
Let $x = 1-u^{1/3}$, then $u = (1-x)^3$ and $\dd u = -3(1-x)^2 \dd x$. Substitute it into the integral, we turn it into
$$
\int_0^1 3(1-x)^2 \log x\ \dd x
= \int_0^1 \boxed{(3x^2 - 6x + 3) \log x}\dd x.
$$
Now those derivatives are much simpler, so let's guess the integral by parts.

$\dd(x^n \log x) = x^{n-1}\dd x + nx^{n-1} \log x\ \dd x$.
$\dd((x^3 - 3x^2+3x) \log x) = (x^2-3x+3)\dd x + \boxed{(3x^2-6x+3) \log x}\dd x$.
Note that $(x^2-3x+3)\dd x = \dd\left(\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{3x^2}2 + 3x \right)$, so we can work out that $$f = (x^3 - 3x^2+3x) \log x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{3x^2}2 - 3x$$ satisfies $\dd f = \boxed{(3x^2-6x+3) \log x}\dd x$.

(Wolfram|Alpha gives the same result.)
When $x=1$, $f = 0 - \frac13 + \frac32 - 3 = -\frac{11}{6}$.
When $x \to 0^+$, the polynomial part goes to $0$, and $\log x \to -\infty$, $x^3 - 3x^2+3x \sim 3x$, therefore
$$
(x^3 - 3x^2+3x) \log x
\sim 3x \log x \to 0.
$$
Now we know the integral equals to $-\frac{11}{6} - 0 = -\frac{11}{6}$.

Thank you so much for your response! However, you did mention that I have a wrong question in the sense that $v$ should be $1-u^{1/3}$ rather than $1-u$ in the third-to-last line of $I_1$. Do you mind guiding me through the process of changing $v$ into $1-u^{1/3}$? I am not quite sure how to arrive there. Cheers!

@KarelDwinugrohoBowosebua Sure! Hmm… Do you remember where you introduces $v$? You write: “Note that $I_2 = \cdots$. Letting $v=1−u^{1/3}$, …” Is further explanation still needed?

Oh, you're right... silly me! Thanks a lot for the correction! :)

Ha, we all do such things. Nevertheless you ask a really good question: wonderful series method, how an improper integral converges, ways to comprehend polynomial $\times \log$, …
